# Electron Restful Api Without react or any other express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, electron, desktop-application

I was going through electron js but the problem that I'm facing is in writing restful API. There are hardly any resources that show utilization of API without react.js, express and falcon vue.js. I wrote python API to add two numbers just for testing but I'm clueless about how to consume those restful API in electron without any other language such as react/express/falcon as it would increase my learning curve.
Help appreciated.

note: My API is hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two built-in methods that you can use instead of using frameworks like *axios*, *jQuery Ajax*, ...

**Fetch:**

Using Fetch API is really simple. Just pass the URL, the path to the resource you want to fetch, to fetch() method.

simple GET method:

```
//simple GET method
fetch('/js/users.json')
    .then(response => {
        // handle response data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle errors
    });
```

other methods like `POST`, `DELETE`,...:

```
// some data to post
const user = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Lilly',
    job_title: 'Software Engineer'
};

// options of fetch
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users', options)
    .then(response => {
        // handle response data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle errors
    });
```

**XML HttpRequest:**

`XMLHttpRequest` is a built-in browser object that allows to make HTTP requests in JavaScript.

1. Create XMLHttpRequest:

   ```
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ```
2. Initialize it, usually right after new XMLHttpRequest:

   ```
   xhr.open(method, URL, [async, user, password])
   ```

   - `method` – HTTP-method. Usually `"GET"` or `"POST"`.
   - `URL` – the URL to request, a string, can be URL object.
   - `async` – if explicitly set to `false`, then the request is synchronous, we’ll cover that a bit later.
   - `user`, `password` – login and password for basic HTTP auth (if required).
3. Send it out.

   ```
   xhr.send([body])
   ```

   This method opens the connection and sends the request to server. The optional 
   body parameter contains the request body.

   Some request methods like GET do not have a body. And some of them like POST 
   use body to send the data to the server. We’ll see examples of that later.
4. Listen to xhr events for response.

   These three events are the most widely used:

   - `load` – when the request is complete (even if HTTP status is like 400 or 500), and the response is fully downloaded.
   - `error` – when the request couldn’t be made, e.g. network down or invalid URL.
   - `progress` – triggers periodically while the response is being downloaded, reports how much has been downloaded.

     ```
     xhr.onload = function() {
         alert(`Loaded: ${xhr.status} ${xhr.response}`);
     };

     xhr.onerror = function() { // only triggers if the request couldn't be 
     made at all
          alert(`Network Error`);
     };

     xhr.onprogress = function(event) { // triggers periodically
     // event.loaded - how many bytes downloaded
     // event.lengthComputable = true if the server sent Content-Length 
     // header
     // event.total - total number of bytes (if lengthComputable)
         alert(`Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total}`);
     };
     ```